# whitelisting some domains & some users on specific domains as destinations for Zentyal/Postfix

Tags: postfix, roundcube, zentyal

I have been using sendmail as MTA & SquirrelMail for webmail. I used to have following setup to restrict recepient in SquirrelMail. SquirrelMail had a plugin called Recepientrestrictions which can check two php files

1. `Config.PHP` - contains list of different domains where my domain user can send mails (sysadmins & Directors of company can send mails to anybody)
2. `recepientrestrictions.php` - contains list of specific addresses such as user@gmail.com or user1@yahoo.com to whom my domain user can send mail.(again sysadmin & Directors of company can send mails to anybody)

Now the problem is:

I am migrating to Zentyal as email server. Zentyal uses Postfix in background & Roundcube for webmail.

I have got a partial solution which is a general rule for all users in my domain (couldn't seperate sysadmin/ directors to send mail to anybody on internet)  which restricts mails delivered to specific domains which is as follows.

1. Add this into main.cf:

   ```
   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access 
               hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_domains, reject
   ```
2. `/etc/postfix/recipient_domains` is the whitelist file:

   ```
   mycompany.com OK 
   anotherdomain.com OK
   ```
3. Generate hash file: `postmap /etc/postfix/recipient_domains`
4. Restart postfix service.

Even after this it doesn't block a mail sent to **anybody@gmail.com** or **anybody@yahoo.com** . Also I want to enable sending mail to few mail id's on webmail providers with the help of a whitelist file.
e.g.

```
somebody@gmail.com OK
somebody@yahoo.com OK
foo@gmail.com OK
```

In short the scheme is :

- Group1 sends mail to anybody on the planet.
- Group2 sends mail thro' two whitelists 1) domain wise 2) specific users of webmail.

Question is how to achieve this scheme?

Comment: this is not a duplicate but some what simillar. What we want is control over who is receiving mail, sent from our server?

Answer (score 0):

To check the access of a user for a mail address, use the [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) parameter:

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_login_maps
```

Use entries like:

```
bob@example.com bob
alice@example.com alice
@bob.example.com bob
```

The second column is the login name (used for authentication). For more information look at the docs. This example uses a hashtable, but you can also use a database or whatever you want to use.